# org-date-from-calendar returns yesterday's date: how to initialize and refresh Calendar Buffer

Tags: org-mode, calendar

From where is the current date as known by org-mode taken? Do I need to perhaps adjust some TimeZone settings? Or is the date determined by the date my Emacs session was started. I close emacs pretty rarely.

Some more info:

After a restart, `org-date-from-calendar` give me

```
No buffer named *Calendar*
```

However if I first do `org-time-stamp` which will pop up a Calendar buffer to let me select a date, and then later use `org-date-from-calendar` we're back in business and the date is current.

So it seems that the Calendar buffer needs to be initialized an also refreshed somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'd ordinarily call `org-date-from-calendar` directly. It returns the date under point in a calendar buffer. But it doesn't actually show you the calendar, so calling it without one of the helper functions associated is going to be confusing.

Probably easier is to use `org-timestamp` (`C-c .`)or `org-timestamp-inactive` (`C-c !`), which do show you the calendar so you can see what you're selecting.

Comment: I have org-date-from-calendar in some Capture templates where I don't want to have to interactively choose a date. What you're saying is inline with what I've seen from some more investigation and I've updated the question a bit.

Comment: I don't think `org-date-from-calendar` is going to be useful in a capture template - it's for interactive use, and in a program there's really no way to know what date it will return.

Comment: Went through and replaced all that with %t and %u depending on if I want active or inactive timestamps. Seems to do what I expect. Accepted you answer.